# amazon s3 upload a file with public permission

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm using the Amazon Java SDK and trying to upload a file, but by default it has restricted permissions. The example on their website does not show the solution, but I have found C# version with the function.

Is it possible for Java?

Comment: I see you haven't accepted a single answer in your 24 asked questions. [_Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

When you create the `PutObjectRequest` object, you can call the [`withCannedAcl`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#withCannedAcl(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList)) method on it to set the optional pre-configured access control policy to use for the new object:

```
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

`withCannedAcl` method accepts one of the [`CannedAccessControlList`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CannedAccessControlList.html) enum constants as argument:

- `AuthenticatedRead`
- `BucketOwnerFullControl`
- `BucketOwnerRead`
- `LogDeliveryWrite`
- `Private`
- `PublicRead`
- `PublicReadWrite`